# Реализация множественного выбора

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

имеется таблица с данными о пользователе, в первом столбце таблицы есть чекбоксы, в заголовке таблицы так же чекбокс(который при нажатии должен выделять все чекбоксы или отменять выделение чекбоксов), при нажатии кнопки "Удалить выделенное" из базы данных должны удаляться отмеченные пользователи. Как реализовать описанное выше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать таким образом:

**Клиентская часть**

По-умолчанию мы предполагаем, что в HTML-разметке вы указали идентификаторы пользователей, чтобы у нас была возможность как-то сообщить серверной части о том, каких именно пользователей мы собираемся удалить, она может выглядеть так:

```
<table>
  <tr data-user-id="1234">
    <td>Чекбокс</td>
    <td>Имя и Фамилия первого пользователя</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-user-id="1235">
    <td>Чекбокс</td>
    <td>Имя и Фамилия второго пользователя</td>
  </tr>
  [...]
</table>
```

Нас интересует часть `<tr data-user-id="1235">`, а именно `data-user-id="1235"`, здесь хранится ID пользователя из БД.

1. После клика по кнопке «Удалить» проходимся JS'ом по табличке и у каждой строки с активированным чекбоксом из атрибута `data-user-id` вынимаем идентификатор пользователя и складываем в массив и собираем JS-объект, чтобы получилось примерно так:

```js
{ "users": [1234, 12345, ...] }
```

2. Если `Rails` не в режиме API, то запрос на удаление пользователей не пройдет проверку [SCRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) и вернется ошибка. Чтобы этого избежать нужно подписать запрос с помощью токена, который генерируется `Rails` во вьюхе [тегом](http://rusrails.ru/ruby-on-rails-security-guide#csrf-countermeasures) `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`. В отрендеренном HTML'е он будет размещаться в между тегов `<head>...</head>` и выглядеть так:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="6LBob8HNwd474WJbfWWRDhlh0agbkL4P0hcfNP4/oTbfu4oWEqAMlMsOT/XyAckG719uYBs61R2/54OPw5E+fA==" />
```

Забираем из него значение атрибута `content`, оно выглядит как результат алгоритма шифрования `6LBob8H...` и сохраняем в виде JS-объекта:

```js
{"X-CSRF-Token": "6LBob8HNw..."}
```

3. Теперь нужно сформировать запрос в бекенд и вместе с ним отправить собранные ID пользователей. Не важно какая библиотека будет использоваться для [отправки запроса](http://rusrails.ru/working-with-javascript-in-rails), [их десятки](https://github.com/topics/http-client?l=javascript&o=desc&s=stars) на github.com, важно добавить в запрос токен, сериализовать в JSON список пользовательских ID и отправить его с методом `DELETE`.
4. После отправки запроса смотрим на ответ серверной части. Если все хорошо и ответ прошел без ошибки, тогда JS'ом проходим по строкам таблицы и удаляем каждую строку `<tr data-user-id="1234">...</tr>`, у которой в атрибуте `data-user-id` содержится идентификатор пользователя, входящий в тот список, который только что был отправлен на серверную часть. Это покажет текущему юзеру, что пользователи из списка были удалены.

**Серверная часть**

1. Если в роутах (`config/routes.rb`) пользователи еще не указаны как ресурс, тогда делаем это чтобы рельсы сгенерировали [маршруты](http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing#crud-metody-i-ekshny):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end
```

2. Теперь нужно создать контроллер `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`, например, с помощью консольной команды `rails generate controller Users`, а внутри него экшн `destroy`, который из параметров `params['users']` вынимает список ID и удаляет из БД перечисленных пользователей `Users.where(id: ids).each(&:destroy)`
3. Нужно помнить о фильтрации (strong params) входных данных в контроллер, и не забыть указать, что в параметре `users` мы ждем массив.

```
params.permit(:users => [])
```

4. Перед удалением было бы неплохо проверять права пользователя на предмет принципиальной возможности удалять записи из БД, потому что запрос можно подделать и за один запрос удалить вообще всех пользователей включая админа.

---

Выше в общем виде расписан базовый механизм, есть более [подробная статья](https://medium.com/@TressaSanders/multiple-checkbox-select-delete-in-rails-9481f86d46d4) или [готовые](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) [решения](https://github.com/patricklindsay/wice_grid).